# Jquery Validation for Mobile

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

Here i have HTML:

```
<form  id="referalForm" action="google.com">
            <label>Referring patient:</label>
            <input type="text" ame="txtPname" id="fullname"  placeholder="ENTER YOUR FULL NAME" />
            <label>Email invitaion(s):</label>
            <div class="clear10"></div>
            <input type="email" name="emailP[]" id="emailP1" placeholder="ENTER RECIPIENT`S EMAIL" />
            <label id="lblO1"></label>
            <input type="email" name="emailP[]" id="emailP2" placeholder="ENTER RECIPIENT`S EMAIL" />
            <label id="lblO2"></label>
            <input type="email" name="emailP[]" id="emailP3" placeholder="ENTER RECIPIENT`S EMAIL" />
            <label id="lblO3"></label>
             <input type="hidden"  name="UserEmail" id="UserEmail" value="" />
             <input type="hidden" name="UserID" id="Userid" value="" />
            <div align="center"><input type="button" value="SEND" class="button_red" onclick="validateForm(this.form);" style="width:80%;" /></div>
            </form>
```

Here is my Jquery Code:

```
 function validateForm(form){
var validate = $("#referalForm").validate({
                     rules:{
                          txtPname:{
                              required: true

                           },
                           "emailP[]":{email:true}

                         },
                     messages:{
                         txtPname:{
                               required: "Please Enter Your Full Name"

                              },
                           "emailP[]":{email:"Please Enter Correct Email"}
                         },
                         focusInvalid: false

             });
}
```

Its not working at all i can't add $(document).ready as i am validating it on mobile and it is not working can anyone tell me how to make it work?? i am tired and spend like 24 hours still unable to to it....

Comment: if DOM being not ready is your problem (since you mention document.ready) then including the js just before </body> might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why the ready statement has anything to do with the Mobile, but here:

Your form is being submitted and you have some typos in the txtPname "ame=txtPname"

I made a sample for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/EAaSs/

Comment: Yea i am also not sure why ready statement is not working on mobile if i write it but still mate the code works like a charm...Thanks!!